# Apostrophe(') in SQL data,oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I need to insert data into a sql table using a csv file with apostrophe(') and ('') in few rows.
I was able to handle it using the below method.

Get open_quote and close_quote and put the username and email_id between these two variable.

```
SELECT  CHR(113)||CHR(39)||CHR(91) INTO OPEN_QUOTE FROM dual;
SELECT  CHR(93)||CHR(39) INTO CLOSE_QUOTE FROM dual;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZCAX.jpg)
It looks ugly.I could have used replace but i opted for this method.

Could you please let me know of any other method so that my code looks good?
Attached is the screenshot of the dynamic sql.

Comment: In what way are you "using a CSV file"?  Your code snippet uses expressions `C1.EMAIL` and `C1.NAME` which implies your getting the values from some existing table.  Given what I can see of your code, a better approach would be to use bind variables rather than creating a unique SQL statement for each row.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a single quote in a string by doubling it.  For instance:

```
select 'It''s Bob''s book'
from dual;
```

Answer (score 1):

As of Oracle 10g in PL/SQL you can have:
`V_SQL_STATEMENT := q'[It's Bob's book]';`
See [Oracle SQL Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm) for details on text literals.

Answer (score 0):

Use the alternative-quoting mechanism and several `REPLACE`s instead of concatenation.  It's a little extra work but it makes it clearer what the final SQL statement will look like.

```
v_sql_statement := replace(replace(replace(replace(
    q'[
        insert into login
        (USER_ID,CLIENT_ID,EMAIL,PSWD_HASH,NETWORK_ID,FAILED_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS,NAME)
        VALUES
        (
            LOGIN_SEQ.nextval,
            #P_CLIENT_ID#,
            '#PARSE_EMAIL#',
            #V_PSWD_HASH#,
            NULL,
            0,
            '#USER_NAME#'
        )
    ]'
    , '#P_CLIENT_ID#', p_client_id)
    , '#PARSE_EMAIL#', parse_email(lower(c1.email)))
    , '#V_PSWD_HASH#', v_pswd_hash)
    , '#USER_NAME#',   nvl(c1.name, generate_user_name(parse_email(c1.email))))
;
```